# How to loop in dataframe with a specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I want to loop over with following condition:

```
df.loc[df['P1'] >= 2 * df['T1'], ['P1']] = 1
```

I also want to include, if the above condition is not met, then the values of P1 column should be equal to 0.

Dataframe image link is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the use of the apply function, like this:

```py
df['P1'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['P1'] >= 2 * row['T1'] else 0, axis=1)
```